# How can I use numpy to solve a system of linear equations?

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I've got a system of linear equations in a matrix form:

```
A * X = b
```

Given that I know `A` and `X` I can calculate `b` matrix. And now the problem is that `b` should contain the same columns (`b` is the matrix of `N` 3D points, where the column represent point coordinates) but they'll be different from each other, so I want to find such `b` column (a single 3D point) that will minimise MSE if I calculate `X` given `A` and `b` (a single 3D point).

How can I use numpy to do this?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html#numpy.linalg.solve

Comment: In general, `np.pinv(A) @ b` is a solution of the linear system in MSE sense; But you probably needed to convert your system to traditional form,  e.g. b should be a column vector, e.g. of size 3 * N.

Comment: @bubble I believe b is (3, N) already (i.e., point is a column).

Comment: I meant that shape of b is (3*N, 1); In your case shape  of b is (3, N);  You need to convert your system to traditional form, e.g. using `b=np.ravel(b, order='F')`  and correspondingly restructure the right part of the equation.